# How to store the result of an execute immediate in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute-immediate, bulk-collect

I have a table which has select queries and insert queries stored as varchars. I have to execute the select query and insert the result of the select query using the insert query using a procedure. Right now I'm executing immediate and bulk collecting  the select query into a table of varchars.

After this, I go to each row of vartable and take the values and put it in the insert query.   I have a number of pairs of select and insert queries for a number of tables. So this has to be done dynamically. 
My question is, is there a better way to store the result of the select query? other than using a table of varchar? Because the result set of the select query might have millions of records and this might cause a problem.
Would using a nested table type and using **EXTEND** on it solve the problem?

```
PROCEDURE SEL_INS
AS
  CURSOR C
  IS
    SELECT 
      SELEQRY SELQRY,
      INSQUERY INSERTQRY,
      cols COLS
      FROM TAB1;
      selqry  VARCHAR2(1000);
      insqry VARCHAR2(1000);
      tab1 vartable:=vartable();
      cols   NUMBER;

 BEGIN
   tab1:=vartable(NULL);
     FOR X    IN C
      LOOP
          selqry:= X.SELQRY;
          cols:=X.COLS;
  EXECUTE immediate selqry bulk collect INTO tab1;
 -- select statement is concatenated before executing. so that each index has one record    
 --with values separated by commas 
   --- a sample column in tab1 will have values like (abc,abc1,abc2)
     FOR i IN 1..tab1.count
     LOOP
       insqry :=X.INSERTQRY; 
       --- insert query will have values like insert into tab2   values('abc,'abc1','abc2')

         EXECUTE immediate insqry;

     END LOOP;
   END LOOP;


  END SEL_INS;
```

vartable is a table of type varchars2(4000)

Comment: I'm confused how the `SELECT` and `INSERT` works together.  What are these "insert queries"?  Are they simply the tables to insert the data into?  Could you re-write this to do:  `execute immediate 'insert into '||var_insert_table||' '||var_selquery;`?

Comment: How about a ref cursor?

Comment: @JonHeller By insert queries I meant the insert into statement. Yes the tables to insert data into. And I need the select statement and insert statement separately.

Comment: @PraneethGudumasu If I'm using a ref cursor, how would I get the result set dynamically? I mean, If the first select query is select emp_name, emp_id from employee and the next query in the table is select dept,city from city then how would I be able to access the result?

Comment: @cumberdame Can you show some simple examples of what these statements look like?  I wonder if there's a way to directly insert into the tables without storing the data in a PL/SQL array.

Comment: Instead of storing the results in a large array, you might choose to open a dynamic sql cursor using `open ... for ...`, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#i13057 ,  instead of `execute immediate`

Comment: @JonHeller I've been using an array to store the data.
so, if the select query is    select emp1,id1 from emp_details. The result of emp and id will be inserted into another table say, emp_final_details. 
    insert into emp_final_details values(<emp1>,<id1>). Here <emp1> and <id1> will be stored in the array. And I retrieve it from the array and substitute it in the insert statement.

Comment: Please provide code which is closer to your real code. You generalized to much in order to give proper answer.

Comment: Why do you separate the insert and select statements? Why not just store a single `insert into ... select ....` statement in your table instead? Then it becomes a simple matter of running `execute immediate v_sql_statement;`. Or, if your insert and select statements are in different columns, rather than storing the insert statement as `insert into .... values (...)`, why not make it `insert into ....` so that you can just do `execute immediate v_ins_statement||chr(10)||v_sel_statement;`

Comment: How does insert statement look like? Maybe will be possible to gather *Insert into ... Select ...* statement and execute it dynamically. Or as other way insert *Select query result* into Temporary table and use it in *Insert statement*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have edited the question to contain the code.

Answer (score 3):

As given in comments you should try to rewrite your statement as `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`. Let's assume this is not possible for whatever reason. In this case you can use procedure as below:

```
PROCEDURE SEL_INS AS

    CURSOR C IS
    SELECT SELEQRY, INSQUERY, COLS
    FROM TAB1;

    selqry  VARCHAR2(1000);
    insqry VARCHAR2(1000);
    tab1 vartable;
    cols   NUMBER;

    cur INTEGER;
    res INTEGER;
    col_cnt INTEGER;
    desctab DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
    i INTEGER;

BEGIN

    FOR aQuery IN C LOOP
        tab1 := vartable();

        cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, aQuery.SELEQRY, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
        DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(cur, col_cnt, desctab)
        FOR i IN 1..col_cnt LOOP
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cur, i, desctab(i).COL_NAME, 2000);
        END LOOP;
        res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH(cur, TRUE);
        FOR i IN 1..col_cnt LOOP
            tab1.EXTEND;
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cur, i, tab1(tab1.LAST));
        END LOOP;
        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);

        -- ... do whatever with tab1(xyz) -> otherwise this procedure would be an overkill

        cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur, aQuery.INSQUERY, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
        i := tab1.FIRST;
        WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
            DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cur, ':b'||i, tab1(i));
            i := tab1.NEXT(i);
        END LOOP;
        res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);
        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);

    END LOOP;   

END;
```

Note, this procedure presumes that all columns are `VARCHAR2` data type (with max. length of 2000 chars). If you have other data types, then line `DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(cur, i, desctab(i).COL_NAME, 2000);` must be extended like `IF desctab(c).col_type = 1 THEN ...`

Also, note `DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE_AND_FETCH` will fail unless your select returns exactly one row. If your query may return more than just one row you have to use

```
DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);
WHILE (DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(cur) > 0) LOOP
   ...
END LOOP;
```

See [Oracle Built-in Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) to get the code number of each data type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are able to change the data that is stored in the table that stores the sql statements to be run, this is an example of what I'd get the stored data to look like:

```
INSERT INTO sel_ins (selqry, insquery)
SELECT 'select col1, col2, col3 from table1' selqry, 'insert into other_table1 (col1, col2, col3)') insqry FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'select col1, col2 from table2' selqry, 'insert into other_table2 (col1, col2)') insqry FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'select col1, col2, col3 from table3 where col4 = ''fred''' selqry, 'insert into other_table3 (col1, col2, col3)') insqry FROM dual;
```

By doing that, your procedure to do the inserts is now much simpler:

```
PROCEDURE sel_ins IS
  CURSOR ins_sel_cur IS
    SELECT seleqry selqry, insquery insqry, cols cols
    FROM   tab1;
  v_selqry tab1.seleqry%TYPE;
  v_insqry tab1.insquery%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR ins_sel_rec IN ins_sel_cur
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ins_sel_rec.v_insqry || CHR(10) || ins_sel_rec.v_selqry;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

This way, you're not retrieving a load of data from a table and storing it in memory, only to take that data and add it back into another table row-by-row - you're doing all that work in a single DML statement (equivalent to a builder getting the truck containing all the bricks she needs to deliver right to the point at which she's building the wall, rather than at the bottom of the drive and then going and fetching each brick one by one). This should make things a lot faster, not to mention easier to read, maintain etc.

If you prefer to store the columns separately, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO sel_ins (selqry, insquery, cols)
SELECT 'select <COLS> from table1' selqry, 'insert into other_table1 (<COLS>)') insqry, 'col1, col2, col3' cols FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'select <COLS> from table2' selqry, 'insert into other_table2 (<COLS>)') insqry, 'col1, col2' cols FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'select <COLS> from table3 where col4 = ''fred''' selqry, 'insert into other_table3 (<COLS>)') insqry, 'col1, col2, col3' cols FROM dual;
```

Then your execute immediate becomes:

```
execute immediate replace(ins_sel_rec.v_insqry, '<COLS>', ins_sel_rec.cols) ||
                  chr(10) ||
                  replace(ins_sel_rec.v_selqry, '<COLS>', ins_sel_rec.cols);
```